# Using Powershell to insert an image into Powerpoint

Tags: powershell

So, I found on here some powershell code to copy an image file to clipboard, and another set of code to paste an image copied into the clipboard into a powerpoint slide, but I do not seem to be integrating them correctly.

It seems to run, open and close the PDF, but doesn't actually paste the images in.

```
function PDFtoPPT{

param ($pathtoPDF, $tempsavepath, $firstpage, $lastpage, $targetPPT, $targetslide)

$arg1 = $pathtoPDF

$arg5 = $tempsavepath

&pdftoppm -f $firstpage -l $lastpage -jpeg $arg1 $arg5



[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Drawing');
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms');


$objPPT = New-Object -ComObject Powerpoint.Application
$objPPT.Visible ='Msotrue'
$pp1 = $objPPT.Presentations.open($targetPPT)

$i = [int]$i
$firstpage = [int]$firstpage
$lastpage = [int]$lastpage

For ($i=$firstpage; $i -le $lastpage; $i++) {




$filename = $tempsavepath + '-' + $i +'.jpg';
$file = get-item($filename);
$img = [System.Drawing.Image]::Fromfile($file);
[System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetImage($img);



$slide = $pp1.Slides.Item($targetslide)



$shape = $Slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(0,$false,$null,$null,$null,$null)


$shape.Left = 50
$shape.Top = 150
$shape.Width = 300
$shape.Height = 168


$img.Dispose()
Remove-Item $filename

$targetslide = $targetslide+1

}

$pp1.Save
$pp1.Close()
$objPPT.quit()


}

#Test

PDFtoPPT 'C:\...\test.pdf' 'C:\...\test' '1' '2'  'C:\...test.pptx' 3
```

Is there a simpler way to copy and paste the generated images into the target powerpoint? After testing my clipboard, it does seem to be copying so I suspect the problem is in pasting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

It seems that

```
$shape = $Slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial($ppPasteShape,$false,$null,$null,$null,$null)
```

works